# create! discards a property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I use this code:

```
    @access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!({
      :application_id    => grant.application_id,
      :resource_owner_id => grant.resource_owner_id,
      :scopes            => grant.scopes_string,
      :expires_in        => server.access_token_expires_in,
      :use_refresh_token => server.refresh_token_enabled?,
      :meta              => grant.meta
    })
```

The `:meta` parameter is not saved. When I use this code:

```
    @access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.new({
      :application_id    => grant.application_id,
      :resource_owner_id => grant.resource_owner_id,
      :scopes            => grant.scopes_string,
      :expires_in        => server.access_token_expires_in,
      :use_refresh_token => server.refresh_token_enabled?
    })
    @access_token.meta = grant.meta
    @access_token.save!
```

The `:meta` parameter is saved as I expected. What is the difference between these two code snippets?

Edit: the Doorkeeper:AccessToken class is defined in 2 files, [here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/models/mongoid3/access_grant.rb) and [here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/models/access_grant.rb). I don't see anything that would impact the above code though.

Comment: Can you post your `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` as well?

Comment: Is there any error/warning message shown when you run the first one?

Comment: @RajeshCO no error message, and everything is persisted except for the :meta property.

Comment: I'm assuming this error happens in Rails3 and not in Rails4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow `meta` attribute for `mass assignment`:

```
if ::Rails.version.to_i < 4 || defined?(ProtectedAttributes)
  attr_accessible :resource_owner_id, 
                  :application_id, 
                  :expires_in, 
                  :redirect_uri, 
                  :scopes, 
                  :meta # Add this
end
```